# Apply Generic Pre-Defined Template to Uploaded Document XML

Tags: xml, docusignapi

I'm new to the DocuSign API and am having some difficulty determining how to structure XML for an API request in a specific scenario.  I have a document that contains Anchor Tags (in white text) to be uploaded, and a pre-defined template on the DocuSign server that defines how to place the various input fields based on the Anchor Tags, as well as containing the relevant definitions for roles, etc.  What I want to do is define the XML in the request string to handle creating an envelope for the uploaded document that then has my predefined template applied to it.  I just can't seem to get this right.  I can find documentation/walk-throughs on defining an envelope using a template, and another using a document, but I can't find one that combines these to apply a pre-defined template to an uploaded document. I've spend hours trying to manipulate the XML based on these examples to no avail.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Here's a sample of the request.  It just returns a bad request result:

```
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data

<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">
  <emailBlurb>This is a test email body</emailBlurb>
  <emailSubject>This is a test subject</emailSubject>
  <status>sent</status>
  <compositeTemplates>
    <serverTemplates>
      <sequence>1</sequence>
      <templateId>sometemplateid</templateId>
      <inlineTemplates>
        <sequence>2</sequence>
        <recipients>
          <signers>
            <email>tester@test.com</email>
            <name>test tester</name>
            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            <roleName>testrole</roleName>
          </signers>
        </recipients>
        <document>
          <documentId>1</documentId>
          <name>test.pdf</name>
        </document>
      </inlineTemplates>
    </serverTemplates>
  </compositeTemplates>
</envelopeDefinition>

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test.pdf"; documentId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to send an envelope based  on the template you can see this post from the documentation: [Create envelope based on template](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____39).

In order to add values to existing tabs on the template, you can add to the request xml the element 'templateRoles/tab' (see the structure of the tab element in the help link).

Also a useful tutorial for using templates can be found at [Tutorial for templates](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromTemplate) with example in different programming languages.

Comment: I have reviewed these tutorials and code sample extensively.  I can request a signature based on an uploaded document, and I can request a signature based on an existing template.  What I can't seem to do is load the document and apply a template.  For the manual equivalent to what I'm trying to do, log into DocSign, upload a document, then under the Actions selector, select Apply Template and select a template.  That's what I can't seem to do via the API.